# Why doesn't Spring Boot detect my PostgreSQL Dialect?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to make a web-based Java application using Spring Boot. So far, I have set up my PostgreSQL database, classes, controllers and service classes, but for some reason, when I run my application, it doesn't seem to be detecting the dialect I coded in my applications.properties folder

Here is the code from my applications.properites folder:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:letscook
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>LetsCook</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my SpringBoot Application class:

```
package com.example.LetsCook;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.LetsCook.FoodDish.FoodDish;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@RestController
public class LetsCookApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LetsCookApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my FoodDish Class:

```
package com.example.LetsCook.FoodDish;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name = "FoodDish")
@Table(name = "fooddish")
public class FoodDish {
    
    public enum Meal {
        BREAKFAST,
        LUNCH,
        DINNER
    }
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "letscook_sequence", sequenceName = "letscook_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "letscook_sequence")
    private int id;
    private Meal mealType;
    private String dishName;
    private String[] ingredients;
    private int calories;
    
    public FoodDish (Meal mealType, String dishName, String[] ingredientList, int calories) {
        this.mealType = mealType;
        this.dishName = dishName;
        this.ingredients = ingredientList;
        this.calories = calories;
    }
    public Meal getMealtype() {
        return mealType;
    }
    public void setMealType(Meal newMealType) {
        this.mealType = newMealType;
    }
    public String getDishName() {
        return dishName;
    }
    public void setDishName(String newDishName) {
        this.dishName = newDishName;
    }
    public String[] getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }
    
    public void setIngredients(String[] newIngredientList) {
        this.ingredients = newIngredientList;
    }
    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }
    public void setCalories(int newCalories) {
        this.calories = newCalories;
    }
    public void getDishInfo() {
        System.out.println("Name of Dish: " + dishName);
        System.out.print("Ingredients: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
            if (i < ingredients.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(ingredients[i] + ", ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(ingredients[i] + '\n');
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Calories: " + calories);
    }
}
```

Here is my FoodDishController class:

```
package com.example.LetsCook.FoodDish;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/fooddish")
public class FoodDishController {
    private final FoodDishService foodDishService;
    @Autowired
    public FoodDishController(FoodDishService foodDishService) {
        this.foodDishService = foodDishService;
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<FoodDish> getFoodDishes() {
        return foodDishService.getFoodDishes();
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is my FoodDishService class:

```
package com.example.LetsCook.FoodDish;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FoodDishService {
    public List<FoodDish> getFoodDishes() {
        return List.of(new FoodDish(FoodDish.Meal.BREAKFAST, "Cake", new String[]{"flour", "egg", "frosting"}, 300));
    }
}
```

Comment: The url is incorrect.

Comment: Remove javax.persistence dependency from pom.xml. It is old and not needed.

Comment: @Jens url is correct as it defaults to localhost.

Comment: Add no-args constructor to the entity class.

Comment: Remove RestController annotation from the main application class.

Comment: How do you know it hasn't detected the dialect? Can you share the log output when you start your app?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson 

Here is the log output: https://imgur.com/a/PnXWDXP

Here is an image of my project directory with the packages: https://imgur.com/a/3Kl7mSF

Comment: Thanks for the logs but I can't see any sign of a problem with the database or the dialect. Can you describe the error that you're seeing and provide a [complete yet minimal example](/help/mcve) that reproduces it.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson So I followed AmigosCode's tutorial and this a part of his output log: https://imgur.com/a/UiBrEI0

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The HHH000400 log is whats missing

Comment: Unfortunately, with no apparent error and no complete yet minimal example, it isn't clear why that one line of logging is of such importance. It's quite possible that Hibernate isn't logging anything because you've told it the dialect to use. In other words, there's nothing for it to detect.